# Access vnode of tag element without ref

Tags: html, vue.js

My component:

```
{
    updated()
    {
         var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
         forms.forEach(form => 
         { 
            var myProp = form.__vnode.props.onDoSubmit;
         });
    }
}
```

This code works on dev, but on production __vnode is undefined. How I can access vnode of any form inside my component?

Comment: At a minimum, this is an incorrect use of the framework. If you need interaction with elements inside the component, use the Template Refs. If you need to change the props, pass reactive values to nested components. Events are used to interact with nested component events.

Comment: I agree don't interact with properties that start by __ in your code, that's private vue api that might change without notice and break your app, and also some of those properties will be removed in production. Which problem are you trying to solve ? Those props have been passed to the component anyway, so you have them somewhere in the parent component. Peraps try to use the provide feature instead of props, so that method is avaiable to every child component

Comment: I cannot use template refs, thats why I have to somehow get vnode or inject o all form tags some kind of directive to make it work

Comment: Also I`m trying to get callback from onDoSubmit that is called @do-submit="Save(model)" in this manner instead of just "Save" without arguments